# Array of IO in Xilinx constraints file [VHDL Spartan-6]

Tags: io, vhdl, fpga, xilinx, spartan

I'm learning to program both VHDL and to attempt to implement it on an FPGA (Xilinx Spartan-6 Evaluation Board). So far I have looked at the "getting started" guide [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug525.pdf) which is useless - as it just shows me how great the potential of an FPGA is if you know what you're doing (which I dont). I've then watched the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qx7Xef2LGE) to make an LED blink through original VHDL code, constraint file and finally programming it through iMPACT/JTAG.

So I've taken it further and made a button that turns the LED on when held down which has also worked, however of my vector of LED's that turn on when I press the button, I have to declare their pin locations for each index, as below;

```
NET "LED(0)" LOC = "D17";
NET "LED(1)" LOC = "AB4";
NET "LED(2)" LOC = "D21";
NET "LED(3)" LOC = "W15";
NET "CLK" LOC = "K21";
NET "BUTTON" LOC = "F3";
```

How do I declare the entire array of LED(0) to LED(3) in one line? There must be another way given how large a  `std_logic_vector`  can be.

As a follow up question, if anybody knows of any resources, tutorials, videos or even books that can help me with the basics of actually programming a Spartan-6 (or equivalent) FPGA from a novice level, that would be massively appreciated!

Many thanks!

David

Comment: Each element in the LED vector is mapped to an unique pin on the chip so there is no point in not doing it on multiple lines. Since you are using Spartan-6 you are forced to use the old Xilinx ISE toolchain instead of the never Vivado which is much better and for example has more advanced constraints files in the form of TCL scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xilinx UCF files support placeholders like `*` and `?`. But unfortunately pin locations have no order or pattern so you can only assign them one by one.

Our [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) tries to minimize the end user work by providing ready to use UCF files with meaningful signal names. It's possible to load multiple UCF files into one project.

Here is an [Virtex-5 example](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/tree/master/ucf/ML505). There are also XDC files for the Vivado toolchain.

Comment: Ah okay - so if the pins had been sequential e.g. D0 to D3 it would have been possible?

Comment: Not really because you have for ex. 8 LEDs but `D?` matches 10 pins. But it's possible to assign `IOSTANDARD` or `DRIVE` to *all* LED pins.